# Sig-In with Paypal on Android App with REST API

Tags: android, rest, paypal, secret-key

So, I know the paypal sdk for Android is deprecated. I decided to use rest api, but I'm not sure how to hide the secret key that I need to get access tokens from paypal's server. I thought maybe I could set up a function in "firebase functions" but I discovered that outbound connections are possible only if one has the premium plan...obviously. Now I dont know how to do this with a simple php server; so that new users that sign in on my android app will be registered in the "firebase database" after receiving the paypal id-token from my php server. All of that without exposing the api secret and without using firebase functions for outbound connections.

Come on guys, just tell me how should I set the question. I don't need the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sqlciper](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher) to store any sensitive information, like the secret key, on the Android device.

As for the network calls, it's not a complete solution, but running queries over https should be the start.

Comment: Nice tool. So you say to store the api secret inside the smartphone. So then I'll have to set up something like a webview to send the https query to paypal and wait for the 302 redirect that contains the access token(how?). Won't the api secret be readable during the https request?